# How does one launch the 64-bit PowerShell process, regardless if doing so from a 32-bit or 64-bit process?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to launch the 64-bit version of PowerShell.exe
I verify that I'm in the 64-bit version by checking the value of [system.intptr]::size is 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To launch a 64-bit version of PowerShell:

- From a 32-bit process, use path:

  ```
  c:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
  ```
- From a 64-bit process, use path:

  ```
  c:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
  ```

If you make a mistake, and launch:

```
    c:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

from a 32-bit process, you'll get the 32-bit version of PowerShell.  And if you mistakenly launch:

```
    c:\windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

from a 64-bit process, you'll get an error because from a 64-bit process the `c:\windows\sysnative\` path is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way of launching the executable corresponding to the OS Architecture:

```
# Get default executable path
$exePath = Join-Path $PSHome powershell.exe

# Test bitness
if([System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem -xor [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess){
    # 32-bit process on 64-bit OS
    $exePath = $exePath -replace 'syswow64','sysnative'
}

# Launch new shell
& $exePath 'arguments go here'
```

Comment: Should not it be `-replace 'SysWOW64', 'sysnative'` instead of `-replace 'system32','sysnative'`?

Comment: This is good to know, but the question was not related to the OS architecture.   The question applies only to 64-bit OS.   Within a 64-bit OS, you can run a 64-bit process or a 32-bit process.  How does such a process ensure they launch the 64-bit version of PowerShell.  That's the question.