# Running 64bit powershell from 32bit python

Tags: python, powershell, 32bit-64bit

I'm running on `Windows Server 2012 R2 standard` machine with 32Bit python.
I'm trying to run a powershell script for a 64Bit system which check if a key exists in the registry:

```
$path = "Registry::HKLM\Software\<folder>"
if (!(Test-Path $path)) 
   {
       write "$path does not exist!"
   }
```

When running through powershell, script works perfect.
When I'm running it from python, it doesn't find the key:

```
from gevent.subprocess import call
call("powershell <script.ps1>, shell=True")
```

After some research, I found that the 32bit **python** process is calling the 32bit version of **powershell**.
I verified it with this simple script that checks if the process running is 32bit or 64bit:

```
powershell [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

Will return `True` for 64Bit process and `False` for a 32Bit process.
Manually checking this command works:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

Returns `False` as this is the 32Bit version of powershell (yes, quite confusing due to the WOW64 folder).

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

Returns `True`.
But running:

```
from gevent.subprocess import call
call("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess", shell=True)
```

Returns `False`
What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 64-bit DLLs go to System32 and 32-bit DLLs to SysWoW64 on 64-bit Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949959/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-to-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-to-syswow64-on-64-bit-windows)

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that Windows transparently [redirects file system calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) from 32-bit processes to `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` :)

There a simple solution to this - if a 32-bit process tries to fetch file system resources from `C:\Windows\sysnative` instead, Windows will not redirect to `SysWOW64`.

From PowerShell it's fairly easy to [figure out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295073/712649) whether your process will be affected by all of this SysWOW64 redirection, basically:

```
$IsSysWOW64Process = [Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem -and -not [Environment]::Is64BitProcess
```

In python however, I haven't been able to find a surefire way of doing this, so I suspect your best bet is to call `kernel32!IsWow64Process2()` via `ctypes`:

```py
from ctypes import windll,c_ushort,byref
import platform

def is_syswow64_process():
    if platform.architecture()[0] != '64bit':
        # 32-bit OS, no syswow64 handling
        return False

    # Ok, 64-bit OS, let's see if the process is 32-bit
    # Obtain process handle to self
    this_process = windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcess()

    # Declare ref arguments 
    proc_type, platform_type = c_ushort(), c_ushort()

    # Query Windows for the information
    wow64_call = windll.kernel32.IsWow64Process2(this_process, byref(proc_type), byref(platform_type))

    if wow64_call == 0:
        # you'd probably want to call kernel32!GetLastError here
        raise Exception("Problem querying kernel32!IsWow64Process2")

    return proc_type.value == 0
```

And now you can conditionally replace the path when needed:

```py
powershell = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"

if is_syswow64_process():
    powershell = re.sub("(?i)syswow64|system32", "sysnative", powershell)

call("%s .\path\to\script.ps1" % powershell)
```