# Execute powershell in x64 from MSBuild

Tags: powershell, msbuild, csproj

I would like to run an after build script with Powershell. This script needs to be run in 64bits. However, whenever I run msbuild with my .csproj file the script always runs in 32 bits. If I run the same script from the same powershell session where I started the msbuild, the script runs in x64 just fine.

My command:

```
msbuild .\src\Project.csproj /t:Build /p:Platform='x64' /p:Configuration='Debug'
```

I thought I could force to use the 64bits version like suggested on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289450/how-does-one-launch-the-64-bit-powershell-process-regardless-if-doing-so-from-a#:%7E:text=To%20launch%20a%2064-bit%20version%20of%20PowerShell%3A%20From,If%20you%20make%20a%20mistake%2C%20and%20launch%3A%20c%3AwindowsSystem32WindowsPowerShellv1.0powershell.exe)
My target in my .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
     <PowerShellExe>$(WINDIR)\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) .\Run-AfterBuild.ps1" WorkingDirectory="$(OutputPath)"/>
</Target>
```

The beginning of the after build script:

```
Write-Host $"Is a 64bitsProcess $([System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess)"
```

When run from msbuild the output is false, and from the session session that launched msbuild but running the script directly outputs true.

MS build version: 16.3

Comment: As an aside: Expandable strings in PowerShell aren't `$`-prefixed - just use `"..."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**64-bit vs. 32-bit processes** see **separate, bitness-specific directories as `C:\Windows\System32`**.

Therefore, when launched from a 32-bit process, `$(WINDIR)\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` refers to the 32-bit version of PowerShell.

However, there is a virtual<sup>[1]</sup> **`SysNative` directory** that **allows 32-bit processes to access the 64-bit System32 directory**:

```
$(WINDIR)\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

For the sake of completeness: For the **inverse**, i.e. to **allow 64-bit processes to access the 32-bit System32 directory**, use the (non-virtual) **`SysWOW64` directory**.

---

<sup>[1] When *enumerating* the child directories of `C:\Windows\System32`, *no* `SysNative` entry shows up. However, using it *as part of a path*, e.g. `C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, transparently targets the otherwise-invisible-to-32-bit-processes 64-bit System32 directory.</sup>